# Get model-bound listbox's SelectedItem string representation

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently working on a WPF app. I'm trying to get a string representation of a model-bound listbox's SelectedItem.

Model:

```
public class ItemModel
{
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
}
```

When the user clicks a 'AddButton':

```
ItemModel item = new ItemModel
{
    Quantity = qtyTextBox.Text,
    Description = descriptionTextBox.Text,
    Price = priceTextBox.Text
};

itemsListBox.Items.Add(item);
```

When a different button is clicked I want a label to be updated. Here's where I am so far:

```
finalLabel.Content = itemsListBox.SelectedItem;
```

This just prints: **< Namespace >.ItemModel** instead of "Quantity Description Price"

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the full name of your object as
[default Object.ToString() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-5.0#the-default-objecttostring-method)

> The default implementation of the ToString method returns the fully qualified name of the type of the Object

Thus you need [Overriding the Object.ToString() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-5.0#overriding-the-objecttostring-method).

For the override `.ToString()` method in `ItemModel` class, you specify the desired string representation.

```
public class ItemModel
{
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Quantity: {0}, Description: {1}, Price: {2}", this.Quantity, this.Description, this.Price);
    }
}
```

Next, you cast the `itemsListBox.SelectedItem` as `ItemModel` object and set value to Content with `.ToString()`.

```
var selectedItem = itemsListBox.SelectedItem as ItemModel;
finalLabel.Content = selectedItem.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (itemsListBox.SelectedItem is ItemModel model)
    finalLabel.Content = $"\"{model.Quantity}\"; \"{model.Description}\"; \"{model.Price}\"; ";
else
    finalLabel.Content = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use custom ContentTemplate to change visual appearance. here is a simple template with a single formatted TextBlock:

```
<Label Name="finalLabel">
    <Label.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="Description:" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <Run Text="{Binding Path=Description}" Foreground="Blue"/>
                <LineBreak/>
                
                <Run Text="Quantity:" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <Run Text="{Binding Path=Quantity}"/>
                <LineBreak/>
                
                <Run Text="Price:" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <Run Text="{Binding Path=Price}"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Label.ContentTemplate>
</Label>
```

[image: formatted output]

or without `<LineBreak/>` tags:

[image: without LineBreaks]