# Color specific word and color one letter / 2 in a textblock

Tags: c#, wpf, colors

I wanted to know how to color every "test" word on a textblock in red programmaticaly (without using wpf)

And also for a second method if it's possible to color one letter on two like this :

tEsT (cap = blue, no cap = black).

I don't know if I am clear, I try my best.

Thanks for people who take time to answer me!

Comment: use TextBlock.Inlines and add multiple Runs. [example with screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67306853/1506454)

Comment: I tried, but with arabic letter the letter dont attack to each other